# css outer div max-width scale inner image

Tags: css

Is it possible to fit an image to its outer div width which is limited by max-width?

Here is a fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7UZG7/

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="max-width:30%; background-color:red; float:right; padding:10px;"><img src="http://www.acasa.org.br/ensaio/grande/506.jpg"></div>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
</div>
```

Comment: You can set the `max-width` of the image to 100%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it is :)

make your CSS like so

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}
.image-container {
    width:100%;
    max-width:30%;
}
.image-container img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

and HTML like so

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
         <img src="/img/source">
    </div>
    <p>Your Text</p>
</div>
```

As a side note, try not to inline style items - makes for less reusable code. Let me know if there is anything else I answer.

Comment: tk you very much.
Is has already been helpfull, but my scenario is a little more complicated. Some times I have some thumbs on the right of the image that pops out of the page:
http://www.acasa.org.br/biblioteca_texto.php?id=499
Do you see any adjust I can do?

Comment: You should definitely understand more about CSS positioning to get control over where different elements appears where. This would get you on your way:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I think I got it, tk you!

Answer (score 4):

You should add
`position:relative;` and `width:100%`

Like this:

```
<img style="position:relative;width:100%;" src="http://www.acasa.org.br/ensaio/grande/506.jpg">
```

This is because when the position of an element is relative, and if it's size (height and/or width) is given in percent, the element will be relative to its parents size. In this case the parent would be the div wrapping the image.

http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent/

---

Generally the `position:relative;` tells the browser that it's position is relative to its normal position. Let's say you added `left:2em;` to a relative positioned item. You could imagine that the browser first loaded the image without applying the `position:relative` and the `left:2em`. When it is all set, it would move 2em from the left (towards the right).

(It would probably work without the `position:relative`. Although, with todays cross-browser-demands, it doesn't hurt defining the position type of elements you are setting size and/or position attributes of).

---

I have spent my fair share of time arguing with CSS positioning, and I really advice you to *understand* positioning if you plan on working with CSS.
This will get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: You should provide a minimal explanation of what the suggested code does.

Comment: Good idea. May have exaggerated a little.... Thank you for the feedback though! :)

Comment: No problem - it's SO policy to try to maintain a base of well explained solutions for developers who might come across a similar problem in the future. Glad you expanded your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your `<img>` tag to `width:100%;`.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7UZG7/4/